# Match multiple changing time periods between two datasets

Tags: r, lubridate

I have two data frames, the first of which spans 3 months and has recordings of depth every 2.5 minutes.

```
shark depth temperature   datetime    date      location
A     49.5  26.2   20/03/2018 08:00 20/03/2018    SS04
A     49.5  25.3   20/03/2018 08:02 20/03/2018    SS04
A     53.0  24.2   20/03/2018 08:04 20/03/2018    SS04
A     39.5  26.5   20/03/2018 08:32 20/03/2018    Absent
A     43.0  26.2   21/03/2018 09:10 21/03/2018    Absent
A     44.5  26.5   21/03/2018 10:18 21/03/2018    SS04
```

I have a second data frame which lists the tidal state during these three months.

```
   date    time  depth  tide_state   datetime
18/03/2018 02:33  2.09  High    20/03/2018 02:33
18/03/2018 08:39  0.45   Low    20/03/2018 08:39
18/03/2018 14:47  2.14  High    20/03/2018 14:47
18/03/2018 20:54  0.41   Low    20/03/2018 20:54
19/03/2018 03:01  2.13  High    21/03/2019 03:01
19/03/2018 09:09  0.41   Low    21/03/2019 09:09
```

I would like to create a new dataset which inserts the tidal state for all the values on the first dataset, based on the datetime column in each. For example if low tide was at 08:39, and high tide at 14:47, I would like every value in df1 greater than 08:39 but less than 14:47 to be recorded as 'Low', and values after this but before the next low tide to be 'High'.

As the time of the tides change three to four times per day, I'm not quite sure how I could go about merging these in R. I'm not sure if there is an easy way to do this using data.table?

I have both datetime columns in each dataframe set as POSIXct values.

Ideally I would like to produce a table a dataframe like this:

```
shark depth temperature   datetime    date    location tide_state
A     49.5  26.2   20/03/2018 08:00 20/03/2018  SS04     High
A     49.5  25.3   20/03/2018 08:02 20/03/2018  SS04     High
A     53.0  24.2   20/03/2018 08:04 20/03/2018  SS04     High
A     39.5  26.5   20/03/2018 08:32 20/03/2018  Absent   Low
A     43.0  26.2   20/03/2018 09:10 21/03/2018  Absent   Low  
A     44.5  26.5   20/03/2018 10:18 21/03/2018  SS04     Low
```

Comment: This is sometimes called a "non equi join" and is doable with SQL, data.table, or the fuzzyjoin package. It's also possible with some dplyr rangling, but I don't think it'd be as elegant.

Comment: How big are both datasets? There is a way I am thinking of but it may have size limitations.

Comment: @akash87 The first dataset has 102902 observations and the tide dataset has 386

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data were much larger or the join were more complicated, I'd suggest a non-equi join using SQL or data.table. For this size of data, where you just need "most recent value from table2," we can use a simpler approach in dplyr and I expect it will be plenty fast.

```
# First some housekeeping. It will be useful to have datetimes for sorting
library(dplyr)
df1   <- df1   %>% mutate(datetime = lubridate::dmy_hm(datetime))
tides <- tides %>% mutate(datetime = lubridate::dmy_hm(datetime))

# I collate the two tables, sort by datetime, fill in the tide info, and then remove the tide rows.
df1 %>%
  bind_rows(tides %>% 
     select(datetime, tide_state, tide_depth = depth) %>%
     mutate(tide_row_to_cut = TRUE)) %>%      # EDIT
  arrange(datetime) %>%
  tidyr::fill(tide_depth, tide_state) %>%
  filter(!tide_row_to_cut) %>%                # EDIT
  select(-tide_row_to_cut)                    # EDIT
```

Edit: Prior version using NA's in `Temperature` to cut out `tide` rows wasn't working for original poster, so I've added an explicit column in the tide data called `tide_row_to_cut` to make that pruning step more robust.

```
  shark depth temperature            datetime       date location tide_state tide_depth
1     A  49.5        26.2 2018-03-20 08:00:00 20/03/2018     SS04       High       2.09
2     A  49.5        25.3 2018-03-20 08:02:00 20/03/2018     SS04       High       2.09
3     A  53.0        24.2 2018-03-20 08:04:00 20/03/2018     SS04       High       2.09
4     A  39.5        26.5 2018-03-20 08:32:00 20/03/2018   Absent       High       2.09
5     A  43.0        26.2 2018-03-21 09:10:00 21/03/2018   Absent        Low       0.41
6     A  44.5        26.5 2018-03-21 10:18:00 21/03/2018     SS04        Low       0.41
```

I believe this follows the instructions, but it varies slightly from the requested output, since a Low tide occurs at 08:39, a few minutes after the 08:32 reading. The tide will be pretty low then, but won't have reached max low yet. You might want to look for "closest" tide. One way to do this would be to shift the time of the tides halfway back to the prior tide, or by a fixed amount (eg 2 hours?).

Comment: Thank you! My actual df1 has 102902 observations with 15 variables. I tested it with this and it seemed to work okay, just need to incorporate the variables which I left out for simplicity's sake

Comment: I'm struggling to apply this to my full dataset with the extra variables, I keep getting this error: `depth` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a function. Is there a way to do this as a data.table allowing for the extra variables that I omitted from the example? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps your `tides` table doesn't have a column called `depth`? In my code, I am renaming the `depth` column in `tides` to `tide_depth` so it goes somewhere different from the `depth` column in the original dataset.

Comment: I renamed the ~~~depth~~~ column in the ~~~tides~~~ table to ~~~tide_depth~~~, and I removed the ~~~filter(!is.na(temperature))~~~ section as some of my data has NA values that I need to keep. So I'm now using ~~~d %>%
  bind_rows(tide %>% select(datetime, tide_state, tide_depth)) %>%
  arrange(datetime) %>%
  tidyr::fill(tide_depth, tide_state) ~~~ but now the output of the ~~~tide_depth~~~ and ~~~tide_state~~~ are all NA. Not quite sure what I've done wrong here.

Comment: I think the `filter(!is.na(temperature))` is the part that is causing the issue I am having. When that is included it works fine, but some of my rows have NA values for temperature, which I need to include. If I remove this line it binds the `tides` data onto the top of `df1` without merging the `tide_state` and `tide_depth`. Sorry for all the questions!

Comment: Ok, I've adjusted the process a bit so now the `tide` data is given a new variable to help flag it for removal at the end. That should stop it from filtering out rows you wanted to keep that happened to have missing temperatures.

Comment: Thank you! I'm now getting a new error: `Error: Column `datetime` can't be converted from POSIXct, POSIXt to factor`. Any idea how I could correct this?

Comment: I've converted both to POSIXct as you said in your example but I'm not sure how to do it as a factor

Comment: I suspect `df1$datetime` (or whatever is the first table in the `bind_rows` step) is stored as a factor, but `tides$datetime` is a POSIXct datetime, so it doesn't know how you want them combined. `bind_rows` is being careful to make sure the two have the same type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195650/discussion-between-jon-spring-and-fionn).